# Set levels of a factor based on numeric value of another column

Tags: r

I been trying to figure out how to order a factor based on the value of another column all in the same data.frame. I have been using this question as the basis for my efforts:

[R - Order a factor based on value in one or more other columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758243/r-order-a-factor-based-on-value-in-one-or-more-other-columns)

In my example I like the levels of `ftor` set by `order_ID`. `order_ID` is simply a rank of the order. Here is what I have so far:

```
df <- data.frame(order_ID=c(5,3,1,4,2),
           ftor=LETTERS[1:5])


df$ftor <- factor(df$ftor, levels=df[order(df$order_ID),], ordered=TRUE)
```

This is what I get when I try levels after the above attempt:

```
> levels(df$ftor)
[1] "c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)" "c(3, 5, 2, 4, 1)"
```

Based on the value of `order_ID` here is what I am expecting:

```
> levels(df$ftor)
[1] "C" "B" "E" "D" "A"
```

In summary, can anyone recommend an approach where I can use the levels of one column to set the levels of another factor in the same data.frame?

Comment: It should be `levels=df$ftor[order(df$order_ID)]`

Comment: Perfect! @RichScriven is you wanted to put this as an answer, I will accept this. I see the issue. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer here, actually provided by @RichScriven is that I wasn't setting the order of the column I wanted (`df$ftor`) and rather the whole data.frame (`df`). In addition, the indexing was wonky. So ultimately I replaced this:

```
df$ftor <- factor(df$ftor, levels=df[order(df$order_ID),], ordered=TRUE)
```

with this:

```
df$ftor <- factor(df$ftor, levels=df$ftor[order(df$order_ID)], ordered=TRUE)
```